# Invalid `Podfile` file: uninitialized constant Pod::Podfile::FlipperConfiguration

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, podfile

I have implemented a iOS where need to unlinked **react-native-linear-gradient** and then install the `react-native-video` and added all of the information but there is an issues when I install PodFile using `pod install`.

> Below the required version which I have used,

Node Version: `v16.16.0` ;
npm Version: `8.11.0` ;
React-Native Version: `0.69.0` ;
Pod Version: `1.11.3`

**Here is the code sample of PodFile**,

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'iosUserApp_HelloSuperStars' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,    #I have faced error here
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'iosUserApp_HelloSuperStarsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
    pod ‘react-native-webrtc’, :path => ‘../node_modules/@videosdk.live/react-native-webrtc’
  end
  use_flipper!()
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

**please concern on the attached file to check error,**
[image: FlipperConfiguration Error]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error

I fixed it by commenting the flipper.configuration line